# What is the radius of convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

What is the radius of convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n^2}$, where $z\in\mathbb{C}$? It's not of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$, so I can't use Hadamard's formula. Any hint will be extremely useful. Thanks!

Comment: It can easily be written in that form, you'll just have that most of the coefficients are $0$.

Comment: You *can* use Hadamard's formula, since $$a_n = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } n \text{ is a square}, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ for your series.

Comment: Ohhhh. Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Hadamard's formula: If $1/r=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m>n}|a_m|^{1/m}$ then the radius of convergence of $\sum_na_nz^n$ is $r.$

Comment: But as Mark's answer shows Hadamard's formula is overkill.

Comment: @Henrik Cauchy-Hadamard's formula is hardly an overkill in a question about radius of convergence of complex power series as it is a rather basic, elementary result there. That there can be *another way* is fine, but I'd hardly call Mark's answer "easier" than using straight CH formula, as that answer uses a rather peculiar argument that may work fine in this case but hardly in many other ones.

Comment: @DonAntonio, while I agree with you, I just want to point out that Mark's argument is pretty close to being the usual proof of Hadamard's formula, so it's not that peculiar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put $z=1$, it diverges, so the radius is less than or equal to one.

If you put $z$ to be a real between zero and $1$ it is smaller than 
$$
\sum z^n
$$
so it converges.

So the radius must be $1$.

Comment: A small typo: "If you put $z$ to be a real between zero and $1$...", I think you mean "If you put $|z|$ to be a real number between zero and $1$..." (+1).

Comment: no i don't  mean that

Comment: Ok I thought so.